# SQL CONCAT String + Column in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, where-clause

I got a numeric value in Foo.A and it has its equivalent in Bar but with a string prefix ("Z"). I'm trying to **append the "Z" to the Bar.A col value**. I also tried with `CONCAT` but without any success. This following codes returns "Unknown column Z".

```
UPDATE Foo, Bar
SET Foo.B = Bar.B
WHERE Foo.A = Z + Bar.A
```

For example 14 (Foo.A) = Z14 (Bar.A).

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: To start with, the Z will have to be a quoted string literal `'Z'`. Beyond that, concatenation method varies by database engine.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I just noticed. Thank you. I'll specify my engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your syntax works, then it is likely you are using MySQL.  In any case, the problem is that you need quotes around string constants.  So try this:

```
UPDATE Foo join
       Bar
       on Foo.A = concat('Z', Bar.A)
    SET Foo.B = Bar.B;
```

You should always use single quotes for string and date constants, regardless of the database.  That is the ANSI standard and it reduced the possibility of error.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the single quotes around Z i.e. your code should be:

```
UPDATE Foo, Bar
SET Foo.B = Bar.B
WHERE Foo.A = CONCAT('Z', Bar.A);
```

Comment: Does `+` really work for string concatenation in MySQL?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson You are correct, `+` does not work in MySQL. Corrected the code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found it. I missed the `""` in `CONCAT`.

This is working:

```
UPDATE Foo, Bar
SET Foo.B = Bar.B
WHERE Foo.A = CONCAT("Z", Bar.A)
```

Answer (score -1):

Where is you join statement you are using table B in the update statement and table A in the where condition. This is not gonna work

Comment: Instead of just saying "this can't work" it would be helpful to explain why and ways to work around it if any.